# magento2 - how to create Scheduled Changes (Magento_CatalogStaging module) of product programmatically?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2.1, special-price, catalog-staging

I want to set "Special Price" for product from date to date programmatically by code but don't know how, i use Magento 2 EE. I can set in admin use

[image]

**then**
[image]

but I want use code to set programmatically. If anyone know, please advice.

Comment: Seem that you're using Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Yes, i using EE version

Answer (score 8):

like Igor already mention you can try with the following.
First, create scheduled update instance and set name, start and end time.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $updateRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $updateFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface
 */
protected $localeDate;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface
 */
protected $productStaging;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager
 */
protected $versionManager;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepositoryInterface
 * @param \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterfaceFactory $updateFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface
 * @param \Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface $productStagingInterface
 * @param \Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManagerFactory $versionManagerFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterfaceFactory $updateFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface $productStagingInterface,
    \Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManagerFactory $versionManagerFactory
){
    $this->updateRepository = $updateRepositoryInterface;
    $this->updateFactory = $updateFactory;
    $this->localeDate = $localeDate;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepositoryInterface;
    $this->productStaging = $productStagingInterface;
    $this->versionManager = $versionManagerFactory->create();
}


    /** @var \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterface $schedule */
    $schedule = $this->updateFactory->create();
    $schedule->setName("test update");
    $timestampStart = $this->localeDate->scopeTimeStamp() + 3600; 
    $date = new \DateTime('@' . $timestampStart, new \DateTimeZone('UTC')); 
    $schedule->setStartTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    $timestampEnd = $timestampStart + (60 * 60 * 24);
    $date = new \DateTime('@' . $timestampEnd, new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $schedule->setEndTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

If we omit setting the end date, scheduled update will run indefinitely.
At the end, save scheduled update and set it's version.

```
    // @var  \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterface
    $stagingRepo = $this->updateRepository->save($schedule);
    $this->versionManager->setCurrentVersionId($stagingRepo->getId());
```

Next, create product updates

```
    $repository = $this->productRepository;
    $product = $repository->get('239487');
    $name = $product->getName();
    $product->setName($name . " - New");
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $product->setSpecialPrice($price - 10);
```

And the last step is to schedule product updates

```
    $this->productStaging->schedule($product, $stagingRepo->getId());
```

I wrote a small example and it can be found [here](http://trive.digital/writing/create-scheduled-changes-programatically-in-magento-2-enterprise)

Comment: It was life saving solution.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how to check if there is an existing schedule for a product?

Answer (score 0):

You can use API for this. First, you may need to retrieve update using **`\Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface`**, then you can create a different version of the product using **`\Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface`**.

I didn't try it myself. Let me know if it doesn't work and I will look more into it.

Comment: Hi @igor-melnykov , think same u too, but i don't know type of data send to API, i'm try but data when send to API was wrong so it fail, pls look more into it, thanks